# how to load or import a url in processing 3.4?

Tags: json, processing, ndjson

I am trying to load `.ndjson` files from Google Cloud to Processing 3.4 so that I can select one of the file from the cloud and use it.

This is the code I tried:

```
import cbl.quickdraw.*;
JSONObject json;
QuickDraw qd;
void setup() {
  json = loadJSONObject("https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/quickdraw_dataset/full/simplified/"); 
  qd = new QuickDraw(this, json.getString("brain"));
}

void draw() {
  qd.create(width/2, height/2, width/2, height/2);
}
```

and got an error as json object text must begin with `{`.

Comment: Kevin is right. Additionally I recommend downloading the files to your computer first as they're quite large in filesize and (re)loading them each time you run the sketch will be slow

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're using is a full website, not a JSON file.

Visit https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/quickdraw_dataset/full/simplified/ in your web browser to see what I mean. The page lists many JSON files. You need to choose one.

You need to find a URL that points to a specific JSON file. For example, the first JSON file on that page is at URL https://storage.cloud.google.com/quickdraw_dataset/full/simplified/The%20Eiffel%20Tower.ndjson